# How can I set a statement for sequence to use 50000 series in VBA?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba

My Statement:

```
Ucase([Area] & '-' & [CorCat] & '-' & [Task] & [JobNo] & '-' & [Sequence] & [Suffix])
```

I want [Sequence] to set as 50000 series. At the moment it is start with 000001.

Comment: I have no idea what your question is?

Comment: I have access database for my project and on the build rule tag for document number (auto sequencing tag definition) use VBA code. The build rule is combine the table as Ucase([Area] & '-' & [CorCat] & '-' & [Task] & [JobNo] & '-' & [Sequence] & [Suffix]) The sequence lenghth of this statment is 6 digits.  But I need the sequence to start with 500001 series instead of 000001.  How can I make the table sequence start the number 500001?

Comment: I still have no idea what your question is. That means you should clarify it.

Comment: You need to add more details!

Comment: `...& [JobNo] & '-' & (50000+[Sequence]) & '-' & ...`

Answer (score 0):

Your question and your code are both very vague so it's really difficult to know what you are trying to achieve. Is this code part of a SQL statement? Can you show more code?

Assuming you'd like the set the sequence number using VBA code, you need to use a loop and then use a long variable that increments by one on each iteration. Assuming your Sequence field is text/string, you'll need to convert the long variable to a string and pad it on the left with zeros.

SQL Server lets you set Seed values for identity fields so you can start with any number you like. I doubt this is what you are looking for but I'm just saying because you have a sql-server tag on this question.